# Scope in chrome message passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message

I am trying to pass messages between a content script and background script I want to save the value being sent from the background page, but I think the value is stuck with in the scope of the message call. How can I store the value outside of the function closure?

**Content_script.js:**

```
var color = "red";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "favColor"}, function(response) {
  color = response.data;
});
```

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
      sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the scope changes inside the callback of the `sendMessage` call. To alter the `color` variable you need to pass the scope into the callback. One way to do this is using the javascript [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to pass the outer scope into the callback. This could look like:

```
var color = "red";
var changeColor = function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  this.color = response.data;
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "favColor"}, 
    changeColor.bind(this));
```

Comment: Doesn't the this in the this.color refer to the scope of the current function, and not the color outside of it.

Comment: Normally it would...but that's why I used `bind` to pass the "outer" scope into the callback. Did you read the [linked docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?