# how to get the Callback from chrome.runtime.sendMessage in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am really new working with Angular 4 and Chrome Extensions, but I have this code to comunicate my app in Angular with the Chrome extension.

Code in Angular 4.

```
public myObjectExtension : any;

public getObjectChrome(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, 'getObject', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.myObjectExtension = reponse;
  });
```

}

and I have this in my Chrome Extension.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     if(request == "getObject"){
          sendResponse({
              name: "Afro",
              lastname: "Chase"
          });
     }
```

When I run the application the console log show me correctly the data, like this.

```
{name: "Afro", lastname: "Chase}
```

but when I pass the value of "reponse" to "this.myObjectExtension", the console shows me this

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'myObjectExtension' of undefined
```

I undestand that var "this.myObjectExtension" is not defined inside of the method, but how can I do to retrive the "response" and assign it to my var "this.myObjectExtension"?

Comment: you need to bind your method to `this` `myFoo=function(abc){
console.log(abc);
}` bind your method withthe scope  `myFoo.bind(this)` now you can access  this inside your method, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, 'getObject', myFoo)`

Comment: I don't know if I did it correctly. Look: `myFoo=function(response){
    console.log(response);
    this.myObjectExtension=response;
  }` and `public getObjectChrome(){
    this.myFoo.bind(this);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, 'getObject', this.myFoo);
  }` Both codes work well but I cannot assing the value of response to myObjectExtension.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560137/scope-in-chrome-message-passing, you are correct @Pranoy Sarkar, post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think this question is duplicate. Check this [Scope in chrome message passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560137/scope-in-chrome-message-passing) but I don't know how to close a question like "exact duplicate".

I could answer the question because Pranoy Sarkar helps me. So the answer is this, inside the of the method

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(string extensionId, any message, object options, function responseCallback)
```

the scope changes, so to alter a global variable like "myObjectExtension" we have to pass the scope into the callback. We can do it through the javascript bind method, like this:

```
public getObjectChrome(){
  let myFoo=function(response){
    console.log(response);
    this.myObjectExtension = reponse;
  }
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, 'getObject' myFoo.bind(this));
}
```

And the code works like a charm.